# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\SupervisorController::edit(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: laravel

Sorry this is very basic, but i dont know what is the problem.

I always get this error when trying to visit edit_supervisor.

Route:

```
 Route::get('/edit_supervisor', 'SupervisorController@edit')->name('edit_supervisor');
```

SupervisorController:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return view('DataSupervisor.edit');
}
```

Comment: You forgot to define the parameter in your route definition: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#defining-controllers

Comment: `Route::get('edit_supervisor/{id}', ...);`

Comment: thanks it worked, you help me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add $id as a parameter like this in Route

```
Route::get('/edit_supervisor/{id}', 'SupervisorController@edit')->name('edit_supervisor');
```

or you can change the function parameter `$id` to `Request $request`

```
public function edit(Request $request)
{
    return view('DataSupervisor.edit');
}
```

in blade

```
<a href="{{ route('edit_supervisor', $id) }}">edit</a>
```

for showing previous data you need to get data using $id in controller

```
$supervisor = Model::findOrFail($id);
return view('DataSupervisor.edit', compact('supervisor'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the id :

```
Route::get('/edit_supervisor/{id}', 'SupervisorController@edit')->name('edit_supervisor');
```

On blade :

```
<a href="{{ route('edit_supervisor', $id) }}...
```